# How to stop Telerik RadWindow from always reloading on the next PostBack

Tags: postback, telerik, radwindow

I am invoking a RadWindow as a dialog in my web page.
I am invoking from code-behind since I need to pass some parameters:

radWindow1.NavigateUrl = url  + "?England,Germany,France";

radWindow1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;

This works great, however it keeps reloading on each and every postback.

How can I stop the RadWindow from reloading? I don't mind code-behind or JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IsPostBack property of the page to see if this is the first time it is loading or a postback and set the VisibleOnPageLoad property accordingly:

```
    radWindow1.VisibleOnPageLoad = !Page.IsPostBack;
```

This way the window will open only if IsPostBack is false - i.e. when the user first opens the page.

Comment: Thanks! 

Telerik pointed me also to the 'EnableViewState' property which worked very well in my scenario:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/stop-radwindow-from-always-loading-on-page-postback.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that **EnableViewState** is set to **false**. Since RadWindow ASP.NET AJAX Q32009, when a RadWindow is declared in a RadWindowManager, it preserves its ViewState which was not so in previous versions.