# How to avoid postback on Radwindow Open?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, postback, radwindow

I'm using radgrid for filling a form. The radwindow will be opened after the **Open** click.

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="create" Text="Open radwindow" runat="server" OnClientClicking="Open" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" Skin="WebBlue" Font-Bold="true" Height="22px" Width="97px" ToolTip="Click here to Create a new meeting">
            </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true" EnableViewState="false"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
<telerik:RadWindow id="radCreatePopup" NavigateUrl="page2.aspx"  Top="30" OnClientShow="OnClientshow" Left="100" VisibleStatusbar="false"
     Modal="true" CenterIfModal="true" OnClientClose="Close" runat="server" Width="770px" Height="390px" Skin="WebBlue" Behaviors="Resize, Close, Move, Reload" ReloadOnShow="True" />
```

Javascript code for `open` and close`

```
        (function (global, undefined) {
            var button = null;
            function OnClientshow(sender, eventArgs) {
            }
            function Open() {
                var oWnd = $find("<%= radCreatePopup.ClientID %>").show();
            }
            global.OnClientshow = OnClientshow;
            global.Open = Open;
        })(window);

        function Close() {
            var oWnd = $find("<%= radCreatePopup.ClientID %>").Close();
            rebind();
            return false;
        }
```

Everything works fine, but if i open **Radwindow** the parent page will be postedback again and again.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888171/how-to-stop-telerik-radwindow-from-always-reloading-on-the-next-postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **ReloadOnShow="True"** radwindow will do the reload on everytime. so remove the code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try changing OnClientClicking to OnClientClicked

or try

```
OnClientClicking="function() { Open(); return false; }"
```

Comment: ya changed it to `OnClientCliked` but no change. Postback occurs